# Windows 2000 Cloned HDD Won't Boot

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, clone, windows-2000

I have a weird old issue. I have an IDE HDD that is on the point of failure the in access control computer in my building. It is running Windows 2000. I went ahead and cloned (using Macrium) the IDE HDD over to a new IDE HDD. Since I am not updating anything but the HDD it should be relatively simple. Unfortunately, the new HDD doesn't boot. It hangs on a blank screen after POST. I verified that the BIOS sees it and setup the full POST boot and it hangs while noting that is attempting a boot from the C drive. If I put the old drive into the machine it boots.

I tried a few things with the HDD including adding a jumper to limit the new drive to 32Gigs but nothing will boot. Which is especially strange since it certainly has the files and the MBR (verified using the PC that I cloned it with).

It looks like this issue has come up before on SuperUser, but with no resolution.

Example of other questions:
[Clonezilla hard drive clone - Target HDD not booting](https://superuser.com/questions/1181694/clonezilla-hard-drive-clone-target-hdd-not-booting)
[HDD Partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLdRz.png)

The cloned drive is F. It shows as active.

Comment: Are you sure you set the boot partition to ***active***??  I myself have made this mistake before.

Comment: No I am not sure because I thought that affected only XP on.
https://neosmart.net/wiki/set-partition-as-active/

Comment: Nope.  It has ALWAYS been a thing since MS-DOS.  Something has to tell to boot loader which partition to point to and run code from.

Comment: Ok, I will take a look at it later. But I remember it only having one partition on the drive I cloned from.  I am assuming the cloning software isn't smart enough to set the partition as active when cloning the drives then?

Comment: Not usually smart enough.. no.  If you have a cd rom on that box, you can try an old version of HIREN's BOOTCD to set the partition active on the box itself. [find it here](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/old-versions/).  Specifically, [this](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/files/Hirens.BootCD.5.0.zip) version should work on a 32bit Win2k.  If the problem isn't an active partition, this cd will also help you figure out what can be seen after a bios boot.

Comment: What size is the old hard drive?

Comment: 18GB. New one is 250GB. I tried it in full size mode and also restricted the max size to 32GB via a jumper.

Comment: @Señor CMasMas see the updated post with a SS. The partition shows as active.

Comment: Bummer.. I have nothing other than trying to boot something else so you can see what a booted OS *thinks* it has.

Comment: Boot something else? Another hard drive? Or boot up with the HD on another computer?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas, FYI, I booted off of a Linux thumbdrive on this PC and it recognized the HDD and I could read the contents. Also cloned the original HDD on a second cloned HDD with the same results.

Comment: I would guess that your master boot record needs to be fixed.  I think there is stuff on Hiren's (mentioned above).. or google repair Windows 2000 boot.  Good luck.